# I accidentally backed up /proc/* , and now I'm stuck with a 28Tb file called “cifs2695” that I can't remove!

Tags: files, backup, proc

Recently my boss asked me to backup a Ubuntu 16 workstation. I wanted to preserve all the libraries and system files, since we have C++ code that can only compile on that particular machine. Being lazy, I just `rsync`'d the root directory to our network attached storage.

I didn't realize you're not supposed to back up `/proc/`.

Now there's a single file that takes up 28Tb on our NAS. `ls -lha` returns:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 delton delton 28T Apr 20 07:08 cifs2695
```

Initially, my `rm` command went through with no errors. But, even after a few days later, it's still showing up with `ls` and no space on the device has been freed. Now when I try to use `rm` I get this:

```
rm: cannot remove 'cifs2695': No such file or directory
```

Following something I read online I also tried to copy a small text file over on top of it, and I also tried `echo > cifs2695`. Neither worked. I don't think it's a permissions issue because I was able to remove other files with the same permissions just fine.

Any ideas on how to get rid of this pesky "file"?

**update: more info**
It's a Dell/EMC 300 NAS, SMB share mounted in my fstab. 
I have access to the Dell Unisphere administration panel, but I can't SSH into the NAS (which runs a version of CentOS, I was told).

**update - fixed!!** 
I rebooted the machine I backed up. Apparently that machine was using the file somehow, although it didn't show up in lsof.  I was able to run `rm` again and this time it deleted the file!

Comment: Is there a process on the system that's using the file?

Comment: I believe your filesystem may be slightly corrupted, but don't do anything rash or without understanding what is going on or it could get worse. Do check that something is not using the file, but my suspicion is that you have to fix the file system. You want to ssh into the nas, of course, and see what's going on. Don't use gui tools for something like this. It's also possible that rm of 28TB simply takes a long, long time. You didn't say what filesystem is in the nas. Verify and test and check, check processes, check file system, check data.

Comment: There was no reason to downvote this question, when this type of issue occurs, it's hard to understand what's going on, how to diagnose it, etc, and it's hard to know what questions to ask. It helps to give full system info for the NAS, and getting all data from the NAS via ssh, don't use that web gui stuff.

Comment: @Lizardx: I agree, and upvoted to counter-act the hostile snobs.

Comment: @lizadx I updated with some info about the NAS. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @NasirRiley I tried looking at lsof , in my personal machine to see if the file was in use. However, I didn't try it on the machine I backed up. I'll look into it now.

Comment: You need to see that it is not in use the machine the file resides on, and it's better to make sure that it is not in use on all machines which have mounted that filesystem

Comment: @planetmaker, yes clearly, although I can't think of any reason the file would be in use on other machines. It's mounted on 10 or so machines. I can start asking people to unmount it temporarily.

Comment: I recommend to power-off and power-on the NAS, after having gotten permission to do so

Comment: If you have an answer, then you should add this as an answer. Not as an update to the question.

Comment: After you deleted the file while another process was still using it, you had no way to detect use of it with lsof, because the directory entry didn't exist anymore. (Or maybe you had, but it would be tricky.) And yes, you should create an answer here with your edit.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to find the process which is still using this file by the following command

```bsh
lsof | grep -i \(deleted\)
```

those files are still in use and therefore still take up disk space. A restart of the service or killing the process which is using the file should release the disk space.